# How to read Azure web site app settings values in Spring boot java class

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure

I am trying to configure some key/value pairs for my Azure web application using app settings section from Azure portal to my Spring boot java class. I have Spring boot project, now i want to fetch some static URL and other config values from the Aure web app that my Spring boot project hosted. How to get that?

For example as below. I have added activeDirectotyEnabled key and value as true in Azure portal.

[image]

I want to fetch the value of the name 'activeDirectotyEnabled' in my java class.

Please help how to get that?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your scenario correctly, You can [connect your Spring Boot app to an App Configuration store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-java-spring-app#connect-to-an-app-configuration-store) and can externalize configuration properties to Azure App Configuration.

See this detailed tutorial: [Quickstart: Create a Java Spring app with Azure App Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-java-spring-app?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdeveloper%2Fjava%2Fspring-framework%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdeveloper%2Fjava%2Fspring-framework%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json)

Answer (score 0):

As the description in the picture

> Application Settings are exposed as environment variables for access by your application at runtime.

So these are just environment variables, you can read them as any other environment var in Spring Boot

for example

```java
@Value("${activeDirectotyEnabled}")
boolean isActiveDirectotyEnabled;
```

Answer (score 0):

what i have done is below in application.yaml file:

```
activeDirectotyEnabled: ${APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_activeDirectotyEnabled}
```

in Java class i will inject value like this

```java
@Value("${activeDirectotyEnabled}")
private boolean isActiveDirectotyEnabled;
```